# get xml values with jquery

Tags: jquery, xml

What I'm trying to achieve is to get all the values which contain "/photovit_action" and for each of those values to be used in an img tag to display the images using the link that was provided.

This is my XML: [**Pastebin link**](http://pastebin.com/bcmfAW6v)

and this is my JQuery:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://test.be",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "xml",
    data: soapMessage3,
    crossDomain: true,
    contentType: "text/xml; charset=\"UTF-8\"",
    processdata: false,
    success: function (xml) {
        $(xml).find('item').each(function () {
            var url = $(this).find("value:contains('/photovit_action')").text();
            alert(url);

            $('#test').append('<img src="http://test.be/' + url + 'canvasH(180)W(186)">');
        });
    }
});
```

Any ideas on how to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try `$(xml).find('item:contains("/photovit_action")').each(function () {
            var url = $(this).text();
            $('#test').append('<img src="http://test.be/' + url + 'canvasH(180)W(186)">');
        });`

Comment: Hi, I'm very close to fixing the problem, by using your answer I get this address as image source: http://test.be/thumbstring/photovit_action/Thumb?authstring=GhOwbRklwF3zmYV3bEK66ZMqrJ74YEKkvBbdErBP&asset_id=16_72&thumbtype=canvasH(180)W(186)

i need the same address, just without the "thumbstring", what changes are required for this?

Comment: is `thumbstring` part of the url value in the xml

Comment: also whether the url element always will have the name `thumbstring`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/p7jvkb11/1/

Comment: the image source that I want to achieve is http://test.be/photovit_action/Thumb?authstring=GhOwbRklwF3zmYV3bEK66ZMqrJ74YEKkvBbdErBP&asset_id=16_72&thumbtype=canvasH(180)W(186)

Comment: where is `thumbstring` coming from... is it part of the xml value

Comment: Managed to get it working, thank you. I used the following code: 
 $(xml).find('item:contains("photovit_action")').each(function () {
                                var url = $(this).text();
                                $('#test').append('<img src="http://test.be/' + url.replace('thumbstring/','') + 'canvasH(180)W(186)">');
                            });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case there is no value element so the selector is wrong

```
$(xml).find('item:contains("photovit_action")').each(function () {
    var url = $(this).text();
    $('#test').append('<img src="test.be/'; + url.replace('thumbstring/', '') + 'canvasH(180)W(186)">');
});
```